# How to compare between two variables in the switch case condition , java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I want to use switch instead of if In one of my projects, I have two variables , one is user inserted and another is a random one , I'm supposed to have a case for when the two variables are equal, a case when one is bigger and another when it is smaller , but I can't quite write it well , it keeps telling me "boolean cannot be converted to int" any insights on how to solve this problem? (I know it's much easier using if but i need to use switch here) Thanks a lot

```
import java.util.*;
public class Sheetswitch {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        Random rand = new Random ();

        int r = rand.nextInt(9);

        int G = scan.nextInt();

        switch (G) {
            case G==r:
                sout("1")
                break;
            case G>r:
                sout("2")
                break;
            case G<r:
                sout("3")
                break; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't. That's not what `switch` is for. Use `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the two commends before allready sugested, switch case will only evaluate the content of one variable. To make your example work you need to take a tiny step in between:
Subtract G from r and use the signnum function of the integer class to create a variable which holds the result of your number comparison: 1 == r > G, 0== (r==G) and -1 == r < G Then u can use this result for a switch case scenario.

```
Import java.util.*;
Public class Sheetswitch {
public static void main (String[] args) {

Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

Random rand = new Random ();

int r = rand.nextInt(9);

int G = scan.nextInt();

int signnum = Integer.signum(r - G);


switch (signnum) {

  case 0:

     sout("1")

     break;

  case 1:

     sout("2")

     break;

  case -1:

     sout("3")

     break; }
}}
```

Comment: It would seem to me that this is what the OP (or their teacher) is after. For very large magnitudes you risk int overflow and wrong results. This can probably be ignored in this exercise. If not, convert to `long` before subtracting and use `Long.signum(long)`.

Comment: I see thank you very much, I learnt sth new today :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't check greater then or less then in a switch statement. Switch statements only compare equality between the value and the cases. What's more, at least in older versions of java (not sure about more recent ones), you can't use variables in switch statements, they have to be known at compile time.

```java
if (G == r) {

} else if (G > r) {

} else if (G < r) { // you could also use an else because all other conditions are being hit

}
```

Comment: In Java 18 case labels still have to be constants. And I haven’t heard of any proposal to change it.

Comment: that's good, it makes compiler optimization easier